# How to configure classloader for ear in websphere 6.1 (specifically wsdl4j)

Tags: java, ant, websphere

I have a war file (actually not my own, it's Apache ODE 1.2) that fails to deploy into WAS 6.1 because of a classloader issue - and a specific incompatibility with wsdl4j.
If I manually edit the classloader for ODE and create a shared-library for wsdl4j1.6.1 it's all fine.

However, the client has come back stating this is not acceptable and that I should provide an ear that is a self-contained install, with no manual steps involved.

I've been able to build the ear file that bundles the war, but I cannot find any relevant information on how to include a shared-lib within the ear - and have that used at the start of the classloader (needs to take preference over the wsdl4j bundled with WAS). Do I need to modify the ear file construct? Or the application.xml?

Can anyone offer any help?
As you may guess, I am from a "tomcat just needs a war file" background, struggling to get to grips with ear files.

My application.xml just contains:
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/application_1_4.xsd">
    XXX ODE
    
        
            ode.war
            ode
        
    
    
etc

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813202/can-i-set-the-classloader-policy-for-websphere-in-the-ibm-web-bnd-xmi-file) suggests a way to package the deployment.xml within the EAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three simple steps to accomplish this

1. Place the jar file in the ear, we
   typically create a lib directory,
   but that is not necessary.
2. Update the manifest for the war to
   include this jar file.
3. Set the classloading policy for your ear to
   PARENT_LAST.  This is required to
   load your local (to the ear) classes
   before those loaded by the server.

Edit:
As an alternative, since you are only using the EAR to wrap the WAR and not actually sharing the jar file.

1. Put the jar in the lib directory of the WAR.
2. Set the classloading policy for your ear to
   PARENT_LAST.  This is required to
   load your local (to the ear) classes
   before those loaded by the server.  I do this via RAD by editing the application.xml file.  It is IBM specific configuration, so if you are not using RAD you will have to figure out what files to change manually.

This should leave you with a consistent war between app servers.

Comment: Robin, thanks for the reply.

2. Update the manifest for the war. I need to work this out (guess I'll start googling!). The war works on tomcat and OAS as-is, so I do not want to build a WAS-specific war.
3. classloading policy. I cannot find where I set this, is this in the application.properties?

Comment: @Gary McWilliams - I updated the answer to address your issues.

Comment: Robin, thanks again, but :-). The jar is in the war, however WAS loads an older version first. "set the classloader to PARENT_LAST" is what I am stuck with. I have edited "deployment.xml" in my ear and I am testing that, can you share the syntax to configure this in the application.xml file

Comment: The only reference to PARENT_LAST is in the deployment.xml that you are already testing, as it is a WebSphere specific setting.  What I meant was that the RAD editor for application.xml also allows you to configure the IBM extensions, but that just updates the IBM specific files.