# Exception calling an axis2 webservice in EAR application deployed on WAS 7.0

Tags: web-services, websphere, apache-axis, ear

We have deployed a few webservices using axis2 at those were implemented on a EAR project created with RAD 7.5.0 The EAR is deployed on a Websphere Application Server 7.0 app server. We have created a shared libraries on the server which includes all the common jars used (including the commons-fileupload-1.2.jar) named CommonsJar. In our unit tests using Tomcat Server 6.X.X (deploying only the WAR not the whole EAR), the application has a good functionality

The problem occurs when the app is deployed witihin WAS 7.0: when we instance the stub class of the webservice client witihin our Java EE client the WAS deliver the following excepction:

```
[4/26/12 20:35:31:742 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException
[4/26/12 20:35:31:743 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processMessageBuilders(AxisConfigBuilder.java:741)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:743 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:202)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:743 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.populateAxisConfiguration(DeploymentEngine.java:641)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:744 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(FileSystemConfigurator.java:116)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:744 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:68)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:744 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:184)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:744 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.mx.ing.wm.portal.dao.RestableceUsuarioPortalDAO.<init>(RestableceUsuarioPortalDAO.java:57)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:744 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.mx.ing.wm.portal.blogic.RestableceUsuarioPortalFacade.consultaUsuarioRestablecer(RestableceUsuarioPortalFacade.java:16)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:744 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.mx.ing.wm.portal.actions.RestableceUsuarioPortalAction.consultaUsuarioRestablecer(RestableceUsuarioPortalAction.java:188)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:744 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.mx.ing.wm.portal.actions.RestableceUsuarioPortalAction.execute(RestableceUsuarioPortalAction.java:128)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:744 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:744 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:744 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:744 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:744 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:745 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:745 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:745 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:745 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:745 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:745 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:745 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:745 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:745 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:745 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:745 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:745 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:746 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:746 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:746 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:746 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:746 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:746 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:746 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:746 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:746 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:746 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:746 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:747 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:747 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:747 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:747 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:747 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException
[4/26/12 20:35:31:748 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:748 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:748 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:748 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:748 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1345)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:748 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DescriptionBuilder.processMessageBuilders(DescriptionBuilder.java:230)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:748 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processMessageBuilders(AxisConfigBuilder.java:738)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:748 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     ... 41 more
[4/26/12 20:35:31:748 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException
[4/26/12 20:35:31:749 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.<init>(ClassNotFoundException.java:76)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:749 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:351)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:749 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:347)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:749 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:83)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:750 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:619)
[4/26/12 20:35:31:750 CDT] 00000026 SystemErr     R     ... 48 more
```

The configuration of our deployment.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <appdeployment:Deployment xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:appdeployment="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/schemas/5.0/appdeployment.xmi" xmi:id="Deployment_1335376658663">   <deployedObject xmi:type="appdeployment:ApplicationDeployment" xmi:id="ApplicationDeployment_1335376658663" startingWeight="10" warClassLoaderPolicy="SINGLE">
    <modules xmi:type="appdeployment:WebModuleDeployment" xmi:id="WebModuleDeployment_1335376658663" startingWeight="10000" uri="CallCenterWMWeb.war"/>
    <modules xmi:type="appdeployment:WebModuleDeployment" xmi:id="WebModuleDeployment_1335376658664" startingWeight="10000" uri="OperacionesWMWeb.war"/>
    <classloader xmi:id="Classloader_1335376658663" mode="PARENT_LAST">
      <libraries xmi:id="LibraryRef_1335376658663" libraryName="CommonsJar"/>
    </classloader>   </deployedObject> </appdeployment:Deployment>
```

The configuration of th JVM variables on the server are like this:

```
-Xquickstart -Xlp -Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8 -agentlib:getClasses
```

What can be the problem, any idea? Thanks in advise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this article:

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/app_server.html

Look for the WebSphere section, maybe you have to edit the axis2.xml configuration and change the paramter EnableChildFirstClassLoading to "true"

Comment: Well actually we update our axis client version from 1.4.2 to 1.5.6, modify the axis2.xml, in adittion we made changes on the server side such the class loader properties and segregate some jars that were rendundante. Thank you and also thanks to @Davanum Srinivas

Answer (score 1):

PARENT_LAST seems to be just for the CommonsJar per your deployment XML, try switching it on for all the webapps either from the admin console UI or using scripting as mentioned here - [Can I set the classloader policy for WebSphere in the ibm-web-bnd.xmi file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813202/can-i-set-the-classloader-policy-for-websphere-in-the-ibm-web-bnd-xmi-file) (see example of how the deployment.xml looks in there as well)

Comment: @dims I modified the deployment.xml file like it looks on the example you post, but still having the same excepction, I'm not allowed to edit configuration on the WAS side, any other suggestions? Thanks