# Is it possible to specify WebSphere classloader delegation mode in a WAR file?

Tags: websphere, classloader

I'm working on an app that is distributed as a WAR file. Among our supported app servers are WebSphere 7.0, 8.0, and 8.5. This WAR file requires `PARENT_LAST` classloader delegation mode so that bundled libraries are picked up in preference to WAS-provided versions.

It's possible to set the classloader delegation mode for the web module in the WAS console when deploying it, and all works fine. However, I'd ideally like this to happen automatically to avoid another step for customers to perform.

Is there anything I can add to the WAR file to specify the classloader delegation mode? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813202/can-i-set-the-classloader-policy-for-websphere-in-the-ibm-web-bnd-xmi-file) and other places on the web talk about creating a `deployment.xml` file, but as far as I can tell that can only be placed in an EAR file, not in a standalone WAR file.

Some information on WebSphere classloading can be found [here](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp4581.pdf) and [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/crun_classload.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try

Click Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > server_name

I believe you could set the Server class loader to the server scope and than all apps deployed to it, unless overwritten, would follow.

regards.

Further info [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/crun_classload.html).

Comment: I wasn't aware of that option. Thanks for the tip, but I'm looking for an option that doesn't require any steps by the customer.