# How to load classes located in Java EE app libs first instead of provided by Java EE App Container

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-8

We are going to use WebSphere 8.0 app server in our development.

Our web app uses Amazon aws java sdk, that in turns uses Apache http-client 4.1.

But WebSphere also has http-client classes in its libraries that seems clash with http-client located in our web-app.

I've found next list of http-client classes distributed with WebSphere:

> \WebSphere\AppServer\plugins\com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar (http-client 4.0.1)
>   \WebSphere\AppServer\runtimes\com.ibm.jaxrs.thinclient_8.0.0.jar

So, my question is: How to load classes located in my app first instead of provided by WebSphere app container?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Admin Console go to:

> Applications > Websphere Enterprise Applications > YourApplication > Manage Modules > YourModule

and change the "**Class loader order**" to **parent last**.

Then restart the application.

Comment: I had explored this option early, but seems it does not work. Seems additional custom class loader need to be used.

Comment: Try Applications > Websphere Enterprise Applications > YourApplication > Manage Modules > YourModule and change the  "Class loader order" to parent last. Then restart.

Comment: O my God!!! I've spent almost two days for solving this issue. I've red a lot of documentations. But seems I've missed a point that it should be done for Module in "Manage Modules" menu. Thanks again!

Comment: @trikelef I suggest you edit your original answer to include the bit about the "Manage Modules" menu.

Comment: Hi the drop down is disabled for users to change. Any other option to change the classloader to parent last?

Comment: Built it in your app by using the deployment.xml document: http://stackoverflow.com/q/813202/940299

Comment: If the drop down is disabled, very possibly is because you are deploying from RAD. Or Eclipse.

In that case, change the classloader order in the application's deployment descriptor (expand the EAR project in RAD and you should see it, if not right click on it, Java EE and Open deployment descriptor or similar).