# Websphere Application Server v8.5 force to use the jar inside the libs folder

Tags: websphere, classpath, websphere-8, emf

Is there a way to make the Websphere Application Server use the jar places inside the application's WEB-INF/libs folder and ignore the one that available within the server's plugin folder.
I am using EMF in my application and the version provided in the server doesn't include support for EMF GenericType, so I want to make the application use the jar file inside the libs folder.

Thanks for any help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load classes located in Java EE app libs first instead of provided by Java EE App Container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604192/how-to-load-classes-located-in-java-ee-app-libs-first-instead-of-provided-by-jav)

Answer (score 2):

This is quite possible. You need to change the classloading order from parent first to parent last. This will cause it to consult the server runtimes version of the code after your application. This is documented in the [infocenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/trun_app_classload.html).

Another approach you might want to consider is to use an isolated shared library. There is a good introduction for those in [IBM Education Assistant](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/v1r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iea.was_v7/was/7.0/Administration/WASv7_IsolatedSharedLibraries/player.html). These are more complex to setup, but using parent last classloading order can sometimes cause unexpected side effects that don't occur with isolated shared libraries.