# How to reset PARENT FIRST in WebSphere without Console?

Tags: class, console, websphere, loader

I am using WAS 7 and using the console (/ibm/console) I changed the Class loader settings to PARENT LAST.

Immediately after that, when trying to login to the console, I can't... and get this error:

```
[7/22/16 16:43:17:498 PDT] 00000021 servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [isclite] [/ibm/console] [/logon.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[7/22/16 16:43:18:699 PDT] 00000022 webcontainer  E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer handleRequest SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /favicon.ico has not been defined.
[7/22/16 16:43:29:900 PDT] 00000022 ServerCache   I   DYNA1001I: WebSphere Dynamic Cache instance named ws/WSSecureMap initialized successfully.
[7/22/16 16:43:29:900 PDT] 00000022 ServerCache   I   DYNA1071I: The cache provider "default" is being used.
[7/22/16 16:43:29:947 PDT] 00000022 servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [isclite] [/ibm/console] [FilterProxyServlet]: Initialization successful.
[7/22/16 16:43:33:223 PDT] 00000022 Digester      E org.apache.commons.digester.Digester error Parse Error at line 4409 column 97: file:/D:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/systemApps/isclite.ear/isclite.war/WEB-INF/config/struts-config.xml<Line 4409, Column 97>: XML-20146: (Error) Unexpected text in content of Element 'action', expected elements '[icon, display-name, description, set-property, exception, forward]'.
                                 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: file:/D:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/systemApps/isclite.ear/isclite.war/WEB-INF/config/struts-config.xml<Line 4409, Column 97>: XML-20146: (Error) Unexpected text in content of Element 'action', expected elements '[icon, display-name, description, set-property, exception, forward]'.
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLError.flushErrorHandler(XMLError.java:425)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLError.flushErrors1(XMLError.java:290)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseDocument(NonValidatingParser.java:425)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:242)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1548)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.parseModuleConfigFile(ActionServlet.java:738)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModuleConfig(ActionServlet.java:687)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:333)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:358)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:171)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:739)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:372)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.FilterProxyServlet.dispatch(FilterProxyServlet.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.FilterProxyServlet.service(FilterProxyServlet.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistence(WSCUrlFilter.java:960)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:500)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:321)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:997)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.invokeFilters(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:1062)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:759)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3935)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1613)

[7/22/16 16:43:33:316 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.core/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:316 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.core/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:316 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.adminagent/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:316 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.adminnodegroups/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:332 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.appmanagement/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:379 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.appmanagement.pme/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:394 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.blamanagement/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:394 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.channelfw/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:394 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.channelfw.channels/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:394 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.cim/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:394 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.coregroup.bridge/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:410 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.datareplication/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:410 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.distmanagement/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:410 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.dynacache/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:410 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.environment/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:410 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.eventinfrastructure/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:426 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.genericserver/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:426 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.highavailabilitymgmt/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:426 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.httpaccesslogging/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:426 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.j2ee.ejbmodule/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:426 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.jobmanagement/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:426 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.pmirm/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:441 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.probdetermination/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:441 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.proxy/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:441 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.resources/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:441 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.resources.database/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:441 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.resources.pme/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:457 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.rm/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:457 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.security/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:457 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.servermanagement/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:457 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.servermanagement.pme/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:457 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.servermanagement.sipcontainer/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:457 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.sib.sibjmsresources/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:472 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.sib.sibresources/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:472 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.sib.sibservice/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:472 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.sibws.sibusresources/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:472 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.sibws.sibusresources.wsgw/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:472 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.sibws.sibusresources.wss/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:488 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.sibwsn.wsnresources/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:488 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.sipproxy/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:488 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.tam/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:488 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.web/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:488 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.webservices.policyset/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:488 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.webservices.trust/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:504 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.wssecurity/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:504 PDT] 00000022 ValidatorPlug I org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn initResources Loading validation rules file from '/WEB-INF/com.ibm.ws.console.zos/validation.xml'
[7/22/16 16:43:33:504 PDT] 00000022 ActionServlet E org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet init Unable to initialize Struts ActionServlet due to an unexpected exception or error thrown, so marking the servlet as unavailable.  Most likely, this is due to an incorrect or missing library dependency.
                                 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/commons/validator/ValidatorResources.<init>([Ljava/io/InputStream;)V
    at org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn.initResources(ValidatorPlugIn.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn.init(ValidatorPlugIn.java:162)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:869)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:336)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:358)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:171)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:739)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:372)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.FilterProxyServlet.dispatch(FilterProxyServlet.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.FilterProxyServlet.service(FilterProxyServlet.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistence(WSCUrlFilter.java:960)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:500)
    at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:321)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:997)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.invokeFilters(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:1062)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:759)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3935)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1613)

[7/22/16 16:43:33:613 PDT] 00000022 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on D:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv02\logs\ffdc\server1_5e765e76_16.07.22_16.43.33.5194692865758439264193.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletInstance.init 259
[7/22/16 16:43:33:613 PDT] 00000022 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on D:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv02\logs\ffdc\server1_5e765e76_16.07.22_16.43.33.6136378125229040759707.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest() 302
[7/22/16 16:43:33:628 PDT] 00000022 servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [isclite] [/ibm/console] [/generalError.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[7/22/16 16:43:33:925 PDT] 00000022 servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [isclite] [/ibm/console] [/secure/isclite/tiles/dynamic_css.jsp]: Initialization successful.
```

I can't find a way to return to PARENT FIRST without using the console because I am not able to login.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813202/can-i-set-the-classloader-policy-for-websphere-in-the-ibm-web-bnd-xmi-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Modifying class loader modes for applications using wsadmin scripting](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/txml_classloader.html) topic in the Knowledge Center.

(It is not recommended, but as a quick fix, you could also edit the configuration file directly: `PROFILE_HOME/config/cells/cell/applications/isclite.ear/deployments/isclite/deployment.xml`)

Comment: I have a question here. If the server-level class loader was set to parent-last, does the above information apply?

Comment: No.  For that, it's probably easiest to use [configureClassLoaderLoadingModeForAnApplication](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/pt-br/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rxml_7libapp4.html).  The corresponding XML file would be `PROFILE_HOME/config/cells/CELL/nodes/NODE/servers/SERVER/server.xml`.